# how to put multiple controls at the same position

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to show some info about a merchant. I want to put an logo image and a textbox at the same position. If the merchant has a logo, I'll show the logo image, hide the textbox. If the merchant doesn't have a logo, I'll show the merchant name in textbox and hide the logo image. How can I do that in xaml? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Grid` Control for that. Place multiple controls inside exact same `Column` and `Row`. Then use show hide to display one and hide another.

To show and hide controls use the `Visibility` property of the control

Answer (score 1):

if you are working on WPF application

You can make use of WPF canvas control and in that make use of z-index property to show hide your control.

check this for detail : [Controlling z-order using the ZIndex Property](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/06/13/controlling-zorder-using-the-zindex-property.aspx)

Comment: Given the tags on the question, I assume by WPF you mean XAML (WP uses Silverlight, not WPF)